# Set default css width from input value

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a jQuery ui slider to change the width of a div. I have the slider setup and working correctly so that the css changes as a user moves the slider.

I've also setup my slider so that it's handle position defaults to an input value.

What I want to achieve is on page load, have the css width match the value that the sliders handle position creates.

HTML

```
<div class="inputWrap hidden">
  <input class="inputNumber" type="text" value="5">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="boxout">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxout {

width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.box {

width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background: black;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".slider").slider({
min: 0,
max: 10,
slide: function (event, ui) {
$(".box").css('width',(10+(ui.value*2)) + '%');
    $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val(ui.value);
},
create: function(event, ui){
    $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val());
}
});
```

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/yLanxgrs/

Comment: css width of what ?

Comment: $(".box").css('width')

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see it in `HTML`

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 that's okay. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Give me a min to think a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the slider's `slide` event, passing in the current value:

```
var slider = $('.slider');
slider.slider('option', 'slide')
      .call(slider, null, { value : $('.slider.slider('value') });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLanxgrs/2/

Alternatively, move the content of the slide event to a new function and make the updates there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your create method:

`$(".box").css('width',(10+($(this).slider('value')*2)) + '%');`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w57dshu/

Comment: Thanks! This works too, another user posted first so I've marked the answer as right. Very much appreciate your time though

Answer (score 0):

You could just called it outside the slider using regular jQuery. Just grab the input value and use that when the page loads:

```
$(".box").css('width',(10+($('.inputNumber').val()*2)) + '%');
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLanxgrs/3/) example

Comment: Thanks! This works too, the other user posted first so I've marked the answer as right. Very much appreciate your time though

Comment: @JoelRosen you can upvote multiple answers if they were helpful